# What to do with spam comments

Tags: discussion, spam, comment-flags

Say if some user posted a spam comment under a post, like

```
Best $product for sale! Check out at $spam_link
```

However, it appears that we don't have spam flags for comments. Should I raise a custom flag stating it is spam (which is slow at deleting the comment and wastes moderation resources), or just flag it with whatsoever red flag that will have it deleted?

Comment: Have you actually seen such comments? We require 50 reputation to comment anywhere on the network, so comment spam is exceptionally rare.

Comment: @Catija Yes, some higher rep users once contributed to the site, after years of inactivity, started to post spam.

Comment: ... Sounds more like "some higher rep users, after years of inactivity, their accounts may have been compromised and are being used to post spam".

Comment: @Catija, it is possible to [comment with 5 reputation](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/comment), there may also be other examples where the privilege is lower than 50.

Comment: @Rob On CS50, the super secret SE website, you can close vote with 10 reputation: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/help/privileges (commenting anywhere is at reputation 1)

Comment: @Rob And how many spammers achieve even that? :D

Comment: @Catija [more than 200](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=stackapps&room=11540) would be a quick guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to custom flag the post.

Considering you need to get 50 reputation to comment on a post you don't own, we might need a mod to take a look since it might indicate a compromised account, or someone actually taking the effort to blend in... Which seems like a lot of work.

While speed is nice, this feels like an exceptional situation which may need investigation.

If they own the post and it seems reasonable, custom flagging it might let us see potential patterns. If it's a spam comment on spam, then just flag the parent post as spam